# putting restrictions on the starting point for generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there a way to put restrictions on the starting point for generating functions. For instance If I wanted to know how many numbers between $0$ and $50,000$ have the sum of their digits equal to $12$ or less I can easily make a generating function. However, if I wanted to see specifically how many numbers between $30,000$ and $50,000$ have the sum of their digits to $12$ or less. Is there a way cut out all the numbers before $30,000$?

My original function is $$g(x)= (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9)^5$$ then I would add up the coefficients for x raised to the $12$th, $11$th, etc and sum them.

Basically I know I want the first digit to start with a $3$ or $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your original function is a generating function for the digit sums of *all* five-digit numbers: i.e. it goes up to $99999$, not to $50000$.

If you're interested in numbers from $30000$ inclusive to $50000$ exclusive then you have a digit which is $3$ or $4$ followed by four digits which are $0$ to $9$. The generating function is just $$(x^3 + x^4)\left(\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right)^4$$

If you want to work with ranges which don't fall neatly on powers of $10$, you probably have to split into ranges which do and add or subtract. E.g. for $25000$ to $35000$ you could split into the range $25000$ to $30000$ as $(2)(5-9)(0-9)^3$ and $30000$ to $35000$ similarly.

Comment: can we discuss in a chat?

Comment: If possible I want to show yo my work for part of a question and just have it confirmed if I am on the correct path

Comment: inside the parenthesis wouldn't the x^10 term be negative in the numerator and the 1 positive? Same for the denominator?